# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'conversation_id'

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-validation

I am trying to make a messenger app using Django's rest framework.

In my validate method I am trying to return the id of the conversation I am sending the message to.
The code below works fine, but I do not understand why.
Here is my Message Model and serializer

```
class Message(models.Model):

message_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
conversation_id = models.ForeignKey(to=Conversation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
message_body = models.TextField(null=False) 
sender_id = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.message_id)
```

- 

```
class SendMessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Message
    fields = ['message_id','sender_id', 'message_body', 'conversation_id']


def validate(self, attrs): 
    sender = attrs.get('sender_id')
    conversation = attrs.get('conversation_id')
    user = User.objects.get(id=sender.id)
    convo_object = Conversation.objects.get(conversation_id=conversation.conversation_id)
    if user is not None and convo_object is not None:
        return {
            'sender_id': sender.id,
            'conversation_id': conversation,
            'message_body': attrs.get('message_body')
        }
    raise ValidationError('User and/or Conversation does not exist') 


def create(self, validated_data):
    convo_id = validated_data['conversation_id']
    sender_id = validated_data['sender_id']
    message_body = validated_data['message_body']
    conversation = Conversation.objects.get(conversation_id=convo_id.conversation_id)
    sender = User.objects.get(id=sender_id)

    message = Message.objects.create(
            sender_id=sender,
            conversation_id=conversation,
            message_body=message_body)
    message.save()
    return message
```

I am confused because my in my validate method, I return sender_id by using an attribute of my sender (User) object. (sender_id = sender.id). However, for some reason this does not work when returning the conversation_id. For some reason I have  return the whole conversation instance, and when the data is validated I actually get the conversation_id. Here is my postman response data

```
{
"message_id": 34,
"sender_id": 2,
"message_body": "again x2",
"conversation_id": 4
}
```

I am completely bewildered as to why I cant access the conversation_id attribute of my conversation when returning my dictionary, even though I can access it 4 lines above, when checking if the conversation exists.

When I change the validate method to the following I get

```
  def validate(self, attrs): 
    sender = attrs.get('sender_id')
    conversation = attrs.get('conversation_id')
    user = User.objects.get(id=sender.id)
    convo_object = Conversation.objects.get(conversation_id=conversation.conversation_id)
    if user is not None and convo_object is not None:
        return {
            'sender_id': sender.id,
            'conversation_id': conversation.conversation_id,
            'message_body': attrs.get('message_body')
        }
    raise ValidationError('User and/or Conversation does not exist')
```

**AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'conversation_id'**

Im not sure if this will help, but here is my conversation model. The only difference to the User Model, which seems to be working fine is that I had manually set the primary key, whereas the User model had kept its default id key.

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
conversation_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
participants = models.ManyToManyField(to=User)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created_at']

def __str__(self):
    participants = self.participants.all()
    user_0_email = participants[0].email
    user_1_email = participants[1].email
    return  'conversation_' + user_0_email + '_' + user_1_email + '_' + str(self.conversation_id)
```

- 

Below is my Users model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False, null=True)
username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False, null=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="First Name")
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Last Name")
is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_staff =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['created_at']

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

objects = UserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.email


@property
def tokens(self):
    refresh_token = RefreshToken.for_user(user=self)
    access_token = refresh_token.access_token
    return {
        'refresh_token': str(refresh_token),
        'access_token': str(access_token)
    }
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough

Answer (score 1):

```
convo_object = Conversation.objects.get(conversation_id=conversation.conversation_id)
```

should be

```
 convo_object = Conversation.objects.get(conversation_id=conversation_id)
```

and

```
return {
            'sender_id': sender.id,
            'conversation_id': conversation.conversation_id,
            'message_body': attrs.get('message_body')
        }
```

should be

```
return {
            'sender_id': sender.id,
            'conversation_id': conversation_id,
            'message_body': attrs.get('message_body')
        }
```

Comment: Ye, I figured that out but I don't understand why conversation_id is a conversation object as it is a foreign key pointing to the conversations table. From what I understand a foreign key is a primary key of a different table, but if that is the case why do I return sender.id instead of just sender

Comment: no. conversation_id  is not a conversation object in valid method. you are fetching it from the data ( attrs) you have a value, using it you need to get the conversation model instance like  "convo_object = Conversation.objects.get(conversation_id=conversation_id)" . now you can send convo_object.conversation_id. here convo_object  is the conversation instance